# How to upload Images from list of Uri to Google Drive?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm showing images from local storage to recyclerview, now I want to upload images from the local folder to google drive. I have a list of Uri of the Images.
I have signIn code for google drive, but I don't know how to upload images from android to google drive.
There is a button, I click on the button it will start uploading all the images from the list of Uri to google Drive. 
Please help to achieve this.
Thank you.

**HomeFragment**

```
package com.example.infilect.ui.home;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter;

import com.example.infilect.Adapter.PicAdapters;
import com.example.infilect.Models.Items;
import com.example.infilect.R;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Items> itemsList;
PicAdapters picAdapters;
Button syncBtn;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    syncBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.syncBtn);

    loadUriData();

    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    PicAdapters picAdapters = new PicAdapters(itemsList,getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(picAdapters);

    syncBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    return root;
}

private void loadUriData() {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/InfilectPics/");

    if(file != null) {

        File listFile[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            Items items = new Items(Uri.fromFile(listFile[i]), false);
            itemsList.add(items);
        }
    }
}

public  void requestSignIn()
{
    GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN), new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .build();

    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(),googleSignInOptions);

    startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(),1000);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1000)
    {
        handleSignInIntent(data);
    }
}

private void handleSignInIntent(Intent data) {

    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
            GoogleAccountCredential accountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential
                    .usingOAuth2(getContext(), Collections.singleton(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE));

          accountCredential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());
          Drive googleDriveServices = new Drive.Builder(
                  AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                  new GsonFactory(),
                  accountCredential)
                  .setApplicationName("My Pictures")
                  .build();

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

**build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.infilect"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    def camerax_version = '1.0.0-alpha06'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    //goole drive
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'

    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write portable code learn how to copy files using [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) instead. This way your code will work with "Upload to google drive", "upload to local attached usb-stick" or "upload to sd-card".

- let the user pick a google-drive-destination folder
- copy content using activity.getContentresolver() openInputStream and openOutputStream

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But I'm very beginner so it will be great if you share the code.

Comment: Sorry, i have no example code for this. Try this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider